# Using " DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sqlite::resource: ... " ) " in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, intellij-idea, libgdx

I get the following error from IntelliJ:

> java.sql.SQLException: resource database/test.db not found:
>   java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: database/test.db

And this is the line I am using:

```
Connection connectorForDB = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sqlite::resource:database/test.db" );
```

Here is the layout of my "assets" folder:

[image: Classpath Thing]

I am also using Oracle JDK 10.0.1 in an up-to-date Linux environment, although I am using compatibility with JDK 8.  All other assets work fine.  How should I address this?

**Thank you for your time.**

Answer (score 0):

You're using an invalid format for your connection string:

```
Connection connectorForDB = DriverManager.getConnection(
     "jdbc:sqlite::resource:database/test.db" );
```

After `sqlite` you need `//` instead of the second colon:

```
Connection connectorForDB = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:sqlite://resource:database/test.db" );
```

You should double check the rest of your connection string as well because `resource:database` does not appear to point to a valid location...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this guide shows differently: [https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/wiki/Usage](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/wiki/Usage)  I did try your suggestion separately, but the compiler refuses.  On a different note, I am transferring my code from Eclipse.  My original code works fine with that.

Comment: Ah, should this be tagged as an Android question as well? I just saw your screenshot. I am not familiar with Android so maybe it's built-in JDBC driver has a different structure.

Comment: However, based on the error you are receiving, the problem IS with your connection string. I recommend adding the Android tag to your question in hopes those experts can help.

Comment: I think the problem is with how the folder is being recognized.  It confuses me, since the images load just fine.  Just for your info, LibGDX allows development on Android, "Desktop", and iOS with just a single code base.  It is normal in LibGDX for assets to be loaded in the Android module, even though a different module is ran.  I do not know why though.  I may need to ask on their forum.  **Thanks by the way.**

Comment: I think the issue has to do with IntelliJ reporting the compatibility of both the Android module and the Desktop module at the same time.  The Desktop works fine to the best of my knowledge, but the error is coming from the Android side.  I have read about the need to use two different drivers for these platform types.  The Xerial SQLite driver should still work fine for the Desktop build.  However, I need to do some research on the Android portion.  There are forked projects of the old "gdx-sqlite" plugin, so I may explore that as well.